# Trying to assign a custom primary key to a database using values a user enters

Tags: php, mysql, database

I apologise if this has been asked before but cannot find it anywhere but it could be that I am using the wrong terminology. I have a working database and all I am trying to do is create a custom made primary and foreign key using a webform input. So a user will enter their firstname and surname. I want to create a key by combining the two names and add a timestamp (Im thinking this will be nearly impossible for two people using the exact same name, registering at the same date and time). For example Mark Smith registering at 1:00PM 18th August 2017 would return marksmith1808171300 (or something similar to this). This is the code I am using:

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$sname=$_POST['sname'];

$time=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$userID=$fname+$sname+$time;
```

My webform values are sname and fname and these are sending to the database correctly as the firstname and surname. however I am getting a strange serious of numbers and nothing else. This is the number that sent to the database: 1503104412. I done this at 2am 19th August 2017 so it has not returned the date/time. I tried taking out the time and it just returns a 0 as the result so I am assuming I have the syntax wrong. Could someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Also, is there a correct term that is used when referring to doing this?

Comment: string concatanation in php is done with a dot `.`, not a `+`. You are now calculating, adding the integer values.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you so much this has been doing my head in for some time now and worked perfectly. I think I have been working on this so long, It didnt even occur to me to think I was adding. And thank you for letting me know this was called string concatanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

$today=date("Y/m/d");
$time=date("h:i:sa");

$yourtimestamp = $today."".$time;
$userID = $fname.$sname.$yourtimestamp;
?>`>

Comment: Use it like this so that u can get your time stamp

Comment: $userID = $fname.$sname.$yourtimestamp

Comment: All he have to do is assign it like this for the $userID